why does my bubble sort only work for about 10 digits?
I am an absolute java beginner and have tried to write a bubble-sort. it seems to work up to 10 digits. I thought it might be because I used int. My names are in german. I hope that doesn't bother you.
My code shouldn't be optimal by any means. i just wanted to try it out a bit.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> sortiertenummer = new ArrayList<>();
        
        System.out.print("Welche Zahlen soll ich sortieren: ");
        int zahl = scanner.nextInt();
        
        sortiertenummer = sort(zahl);
        
        System.out.println(sortiertenummer);
        
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Integer> sort(int a)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> ziffern = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (a > 0)
        {
        int b = a % 10;
        ziffern.add(b);
        a = a / 10;
        System.out.println(ziffern);
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j <= ziffern.size() - 1; j++)
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i <= ziffern.size() - 2; i++)
            {   
        
                if (ziffern.get(i) > ziffern.get(i+1))
                {
                    
                    int zwischenspeicher = ziffern.get(i); 
                    ziffern.set(i, ziffern.get(i+1));
                    ziffern.set(i + 1, zwischenspeicher);
            
                }
            }
        }
        
        return ziffern;
    }
}
    



my input1: 763644
my output1: 3,4,4,6,6,7
my input2:7636449812
my output2:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "7636449812"
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)

since i assumed that it was because i was using int, i changed the int to double and the ArrayList to double as well. then i started the programme and got a bunch of weird numbers that flooded my power shell.

Edit your question to add inputs and outputs. Note that you could have used long instead of a floating point type like double.

check java Language Specification 4.2.1. Integral Types and Values: "The values of the integral types are ... * For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive" - so yes, it is because of using int. But double is not a precise number representation, that will not help.

int is capped to 2^32 what is 10 digit number. Error is throws cause you want to stack in more than you can bite.

you can use BigInteger for an almost unlimited integral number (no need to change the Arraylist, Integer is more than enough to store single digits)


I assumed that it was because I was using int

Yes, that is correct.

I changed the int to double

That will have an impact on a = a / 10, which then is no longer integer division. It will make a having fractional values, which become smaller and smaller... like 1.981329389e-267, taking quite many iterations to get to 0.
Instead of double, change it to String:
        System.out.print("Welche Zahlen soll ich sortieren: ");
        String zahl = scanner.next(); // Read as string

And modify sort to accept a string argument and change the loop that loads the array:
    public static ArrayList<Integer> sort(String a) // Accept string
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> ziffern = new ArrayList<>();

        // Changed the load of the ziffern array:
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            ziffern.add(a.charAt(i) - '0');
            System.out.println(ziffern);
        }

        // ....
    }

Now you can freely enter a long string of digits, and get them sorted.
And you could also change the involved array lists to ArrayList<Character>, and then just append the characters:
        ziffern.add(a.charAt(i) - '0');

Using char for:
        char zwischenspeicher = ziffern.get(i); 

Now your input can be any string, and its characters will be sorted.
